# Database Connection lost - Digital Ocean Database

Tags: mysql, database, digital-ocean

My client uses Digital Ocean as a server for their website. This morning we woke up to a database connection error here: http://renophil.com/ and here http://kids.renophil.com/. They both use seperate databases. Everything was working fine last week and no changes have been made to the website. I checked everything and it all seems in order.

I have tried to access the database status from Putty and get these errors:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
Enter password:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I have tried with the database name instead of root and tried both the root password and the database password. I checked and /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock does exist. My question is...

1. Is this an error because the password is incorrect or because MySQL is not running?
2. If the latter can I simply restart MySQL to try to get it to work? Will this delete or change any databases on the system?
3. Finally, what is the command to restart MySQL in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check several things:

1.check the server is running:

- ps aux | grep -i mysql

  2. on which port:

     ```
     netstat -tulpn | grep -i mysql
     ```

3.If running and on default port 3306 lets try to connect

- mysql -u root -p

If that still gives the error try with the host option for mysql

- mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

restart mysql:

service mysql stop

/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables

Restart will not affect your system

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly when there is not enough memory in the server. Solution would be to upgrade  your droplet size to a higher ram.
Or try creating a swap but not recommended anyways.